# How to apply overflow hidden to div with width 500%

Tags: html, css, hidden

i have a div (div a) with height 100% and width 320px

Somwhere in that div i have another div (div b) width 500% and height 300px

div b contains several divs that i want to "slide" to when something happens. All that works perfectly but the entire div b is visible. I only want the part thats located in div a to be shown and the rest to be hidden. Like overflow: hidden.

But i just cant seem to get that part working
Div b is made with display: table

Example of my problem is here http://www.heboit.dk/test/scroll.html

Can anyone tell me how i solve this issue?

Comment: show some example of your work please

Comment: example added in edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fixed postion destroyed the layout and you need not a overflow again.

```
#mainlist {
    display: block;
    background: lightblue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* position: fixed; */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    margin-left: 0px;
    max-width: 320px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that style is already applied :( And it doesnt work. So maybe i have some wrong code somewhere. But i have included a link to an example of my problem at the top

Comment: perfect. Thank you . It seems to work now. Applide the change to the uploaded version so you can see it work :)
I didnt change the display to block but left it at "table". With block it doesnt use "mainlist background color" on slide 2-5

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'display: table-row' from #mainrow

Comment: Hi. Sorry i forgot to mention that when you click the < or > it changes the margin-left on mainlist by 320px.
Your suggestion hides the slide 2-5 but still only shows slide 1 if i press >